# Add dynamic dependencies read from file to msbuild target inputs

Tags: msbuild

I've created a build customization using an msbuild .targets file to process my own file type with my own transpiler.  It all worked well enough, until I added support for dynamic includes in my files.  Before I had one 'system' include file that just always got auto-included, and I 'cheated' by listing the path to that file as an input.  But while I can augment my transpiler to generate extra dependency files, I just don't see how I can pass that information to msbuild so it still does proper incremental builds.

The .targets file I have now is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)myFile.xml" />
    <AvailableItemName Include="MyFile">
      <Targets>MyFileConvert</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target
    Name="MyFileConvert"
    Condition="'@(MyFile)'!=''"
    Inputs="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\bin\Converter.exe;@(MyFile);$(SolutionDir)..\StdIncludes\Common.myFile"
    Outputs="@(MyFile->'%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).check');@(MyFile->'%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)-include.h')"
    BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild"
  >
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Converting MyFile %(MyFile.Identity)..." />
    <Exec
      Command="&quot;$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\bin\Converter.exe&quot; -build $(Configuration) -std &quot;$(SolutionDir)..\StdIncludes&quot; -file &quot;%(FullPath)&quot;"
      Outputs="%(MyFile.RelativeDir)%(MyFile.Filename).check;%(MyFile.RelativeDir)%(MyFile.Filename)-include.h"
    />
  </Target>  
</Project>
```

In other words: *.myFile -> *.check (for internal audits) and *-include.h (for further use by C++).  In the new set-up I'll have my Converter.exe also spit out a dependency file (e.g. *.myFile -> *.dep).

But how to integrate such .dep file in a .targets file?  I'm definitely no msbuild expert, and all attempts below are results from me grasping at straws and copy/pasting snippets I found online.  So chances are high I'm doing things fundamentally wrong here :)  What other options do I have?

#### #1

Add the dep file itself to the `Target`'s `Inputs` to at least make changes to the dep file itself also trigger a rebuild:

```xml
<Target Inputs="@(MyFile->'%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).dep');[old inputs]" ... >
```

Result:
`error MSB4012: The expression "@(MyFile->'..\Test.dep);[old inputs]" cannot be used in this context. Item lists cannot be concatenated with other strings where an item list is expected. Use a semicolon to separate multiple item lists.`  This means that metadata transform must happen sooner?

#### #2

Add an extra preceding target to flatten the .dep file expansion beforehand:

```xml
<Target
  Name="PrepareDepFileLookup"
>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DepFilePath>@(MyFile->'%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).dep')</DepFilePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>

<Target
  Name="MyFileConvert"
  DependsOnTargets="PrepareDepFileLookup"
  Inputs="$(DepFilePath);[old inputs]"
...
>
```

Result: msbuild is now OK with it, but if a project contains more than one .myFile, their dep file paths get concatenated in `$(DepFilePath)`, so that's no good either.

#### #3

We're getting desperate, so let's move that `PropertyGroup` with the `DepFilePath` property inside the main `Target`.  But as was to be expected, `DepFilePath` now has the perfect value inside the target (in an embedded `Message` task e.g.), but it's null when used inside the `Inputs` attribute.

#### #4

We can call another target from a target via the `CallTarget` task, but we can't pass extra data to that target, so that option is also not useful here.

#### #5

We can call another target via the `MSBuild` task, and pass everything it needs via properties.
But the example above is just a minimal version of the real .targets file; in my case I have lots of properties, some of which are multi-valued as well.  I think this is going to become a mess real soon.

#### #6

We can append metadata to existing items using another target, and then make us dependent on that target to drag in the dependencies.  This way we also add the actual dependencies themselves from the .dep files.  One quirk I needed to add was the `-force-run` part on the `Outputs`; if I omit that then the `RetrieveDependencies` target is only run once the actual MyFile is touched, but I want it to run at all times.  And when you drop the `Outputs` altogether you must also drop the `Inputs`, in which case it can't run properly.

```xml
<Target
  Name="RetrieveDependencies"
  Inputs="@(MyFile)"
  Outputs="%(MyFile.Identity)-force-run"
>
  <Message Importance="High" Text="Reading: %(MyFile.RelativeDir)%(MyFile.Filename).dep" />
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="%(MyFile.RelativeDir)%(MyFile.Filename).dep">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" PropertyName="_Dependencies"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyFileName>%(MyFile.Identity)</MyFileName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyFile Condition="'%(MyFile.Identity)'=='$(MyFileName)'">
      <Dependencies>$(_Dependencies)</Dependencies>
    </MyFile>
  </ItemGroup>  
</Target>

<Target
  Name="MyFileConvert"
  DependsOnTargets="PrepareDepFileLookup"
  Inputs="@(MyFile->'%(Dependencies)');[old inputs]"
...
>
  <Message Importance="High" Text="Read: -%(MyFile.Dependencies)-" />
```

Result: I see the `Reading:` messages rolling by for all .myFile files, at all times.  And the `Read:` messages list the correct dependencies.  But in projects containing more than one .myFile, now all my .myFiles are forced to re-compile every time.  So the metadata access inside `Inputs` is probably still going wrong.

#### #7

Maybe we can use the item's `Metadata` method to access the desired metadata.

```xml
<Target
  Name="MyFileConvert"
  DependsOnTargets="PrepareDepFileLookup"
  Inputs="@(MyFile.Metadata('Dependencies'));[old inputs]"
...
>
Result: nothing changes compared to #6
```

Answer (score 0):

I muddled (and cursed) on some more, and finally realized batching on my `MyFileConvert` target could be the culprit.  Reasoning being that batching probably caused the target's `Inputs` to contain the contents of all .dep files for that batch.

#### #8

I removed batching by adding this to the `Inputs`:

```xml
<Target
  Name="MyFileConvert"
  DependsOnTargets="PrepareDepFileLookup"
  Inputs="%(MyFile.Dependencies);[old inputs]"
...
>
```

And it all seems to work now :)  Though I do not know what the downsides of turning off batching is -- will all .myFile's now be processed serially instead of in parallel?  Though good enough for me for now, since each project only has a few of these files anyway, and they do not change frequently, plus incremental builds are also working like this so nothing erroneous is being built anyway.

But if anyone has a better / more in-depth answer, I'm all ears!